# Как реализовать работу ASP.NET 8 в Docker container по https с самосозданным сертификатом и автоматизировать развертывание этого всего?

Tags: asp.net, https, docker-compose, dockerfile

Есть ASP.NET 8 сервер в контейнере докера. Нужно сделать так, чтоб с клиента (.net console) можно было общаться с сервером по https, при этом сервер должен быть сбилжен как релиз продакшн. Пока что сервер кидает ошибку, что сертификатов нет.

Нужно как-то создать сертификат, встроить его в клиента (чтоб клиент доверял ему), и автоматизировать развертывание сервера в пустой докер (чтоб сервер сертификата тоже сам развернулся и настроился). И желательно чтоб сервер мог общаться с контейнером minio по https (вероятно, тоже по самосозданному сертификату).

Сам сервер у меня развертывается с использованием docker-compose.yaml и Dockerfile. Т.е. нужно понять, что добавить в эти файлы надо.

Гуглил, не нашел про автоматизацию для продакшена ничего, всё руками предлагают делать и к debian команды отправлять в контейнере сервера.

Comment: Любые "к debian команды в контейнере сервера" вы можете написать в Dockerfile.

Comment: то есть в dotnet/sdk и dotnet/aspnet установлен конкретно Debian дистрибутив, его не надо отдельно качать в контейнер?

Comment: а, точно. открыл информацию об image сервера в докер десктоп, там пакеты Debian. Получается, через докерфайл я еще могу пакеты добавить, если понадобятся. кажется, разобрался. спасибо